# jQuery count :visible elements not working

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

Firefox console return 'hidden' for this:

```
jQuery(".popup:visible").css('visibility')
```

Why is that? If element is hidden, why jQuery(".popup:visible") selects this element? I would like to use this condition:

```
if(jQuery(".popup:visible").size() == 0)
```

but this doesn't work properly for the first reason.

Comment: If you log the width and height of popup what do you get?

Comment: From jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/): "Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout."

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `visibility` property is not the same as the CSS `display` property.  Visibility is either `visible` or `hidden`.  If it is hidden, then you can't see it on the page BUT it is still there and takes up the full height/width.  The `display:none` removes it. jQuery is checking the display property.

Comment: [`collapse` and also a valid `visibility` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

Answer (score 1):

According to this http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.
>
> Elements that are not in a document are considered hidden; jQuery does not have a way to know if they will be visible when appended to a document since it depends on the applicable styles.

So I would surmise that you have a width or height set on your popup, which is why the conditional doesn't work.

I'd use `display:none;` for popups anyway, because elements with that property aren't rendered in your browser on page load.

Comment: This is what I want. I would like to be rendered because when it needs to be displayed, it will display it immediately.